# VPN with Ubuntu using local DC as DNS server with Homelab?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vpn, dns

I have a homelab that has various servers, and inside the home network there is a domain control that also acts as a DNS server. This home network does not have a static IP. I have a ubuntu VM in the cloud that does have a static IP. I want to setup a VPN on my Ubuntu server that can allow any windows, mac, iphone to connect to it and use the DC as the primary DNS server. What is the best way to do this that is preferably free?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using similar, but with Pi-hole and unbound as DNS..
The below seems pretty to the point, just ensure your Ubuntu DNS is set to you homelab DNS server and select "1) Current system resolvers" when selecting DNS providers.

https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-openvpn-on-ubuntu-22-04/